# Swift 3 Plural always go to "other"

Tags: ios, swift

My Localizable.stringsdict are as follows. And the locale is ENGLISH,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>numberOfLike</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
            <string>%#@value@</string>
            <key>value</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>d</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>%d LIKE</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%d LIKES</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

but the output is always the "other"

The code of getting the strings is

```
let format = NSLocalizedString("numberOfLike", comment: "")
let message = String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, 1)
```

which is "1 LIKES". Any Help?

Sorry Guys, the code works.
What goes wrong is I am using in app localization, and the plugin has problems when the device locale is different with the in app locale.

Comment: Add the code of, how you are picking the value from file. And why are you using plist file for localisation instead of localisable string file?

Comment: @Subramanian updated, and why not string file is because I want the localization supports plural

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Localisation of Plural, create a Localizable.stringsdict file like this,

[image]

```
let title = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("CANCEL_SELECTED_TICKETS_TITLE", comment: ""), 2)
```

[image]

Comment: my part is exactly the same as your "value" part, just dont know why '1' goes to 'other'

Comment: Check whether "numberOfLike" key is used some where else

Comment: No, it is a plugin related problem. But at least i got the reason why. Thanks